# Get request URL from web page action

Tags: wireshark

There is this a page
https://ksp.co.il/web/cat/8084?search=pop&min=40&max=60

It's a list of items.

On that page, there is a scroll down. On scroll, the browser sends get request to get more items. How can I track the get request URL? I want to get the address to get the data as a JSON.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make a request to get the items from the server. The request url should be formatted like this:

https://ksp.co.il/m_action/api/category/8084?search=pop&sort=5&min=40&max=60&page=1

The request will return a result object containing an array of items as it's property. Use {object}.items to get the items. Then you can save the array as json.

On subsequent request increase the page number 2, 3, 4 ... etc.

Comment: I do get an Access Denied message.
Also, how did you managed to extract the address?

Comment: Pull up dev tools on your browser by pressing F12. Go to the network tab, refresh the webpage, and you can see every request in real time from the moment you refresh/reload the page.